# How to add Header in Listview

Tags: android, listview

i want to implement listview with headers like below shown sample.can any one help me out

```
 --PAKISTAN--
 waseem 
 Imran 
 Asad
 Akhtar
 --INDIA--
 sachin 
 irfan 
 dravid
 --SOUTH AFRICA--
 abc
 xyz
```

Comment: Use an `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a header in a list view involves the following steps

1. Create two custom layout for your List header and List row
2. Create your custom adapter for ListView
3. Instantiate ListView in your activity

Check this [link](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android), it has got a nice tutorial